# Por que precisa usar nomes como br.com.empresa.produto.etc como identificador?

Tags: java, c#, namespace

Eu vejo em Java que os módulos que podem ser importados usam esses nomes compridos, em geral como domínios invertidos.

Por que precisa disso? Tem que ter o domínio registrado?

E por que em C# não usa isso? É por que é `namespace`?

Comment: Sempre a mesma pessoa negativando e não dizendo o motivo. Assim eu não posso melhorar, porque eu não vejo o que tem de errado. Em casos assim que a pessoa acha que quase tudo que eu posto é ruim, podia abrir uma discussão no meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é um domínio de fato (não precisa ter registro) e tem zero necessidade técnica de fazer isso.

O nome é usado assim para evitar conflito, usando um domínio você garante que seu código nunca vai conflitar com algo de mesmo nome do pacote de algum outro desenvolvedor, na improvável situação que usem juntos o que vocês produziram.

Mesmo que use junto, a probabilidade de ficar ambíguo e ter mesmo nome é muito pequena se você, no máximo, usar um nome simples do seu produto ou *framework* que usa.

Claro que pode acontecer de ter dois com mesmo nome, mas na prática isso não acontece.

Mas se acontecer Java não tem muita saída, a linguagem não possui um mecanismo de *alias*, nem uma forma de dizer de qual pacote está vindo isso, se ficar ambíguo.

Então por convenção muitas pessoas adotaram esse padrão, que tem até recomendação por alguns guias de estilo e IDEs conhecidos, além da [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) (pelo menos uma antiga, não sei se foi retirado das mais novas, mas é baseado em algo que está na especificação da linguagem - esquisito convenção estar na especificação). [Veja mais na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions).

C# não precisa porque tem mecanismos para resolver ambiguidade de nomes, mas principalmente só preferiu não adotar esse padrão porque ele não é tão necessário assim. Acaba sendo um pouco *over engineering* adotar esse estilo.

Por exemplo, eles não acham que alguém mais vai criar um *namespace* chamado `Microsoft` (se criar, merece). Ou alguém que tem uma empresa de tecnologia no Brasil chamada Jumbo e vai se confundir algum *framework* de supermercado da Alemanha ou da América do Sul que também chamam Jumbo. Eles não vão ser usados juntos, mas se forem, pode renomear ou usar o nome do *assembly* onde de fato está o *namespace* que deseja usar e tem nome ambíguo no projeto. Mais ainda, a Jumbo Tecnologia não vai usar seu nome e sim de um produto que tem um nome diferente e é quase impossível outro igual. Mas, novamente, tem solução se for necessário.

Então Java quer garantir unicidade, C# considera que é quase impossível ter colisão, mas se tiver tem mecanismos para resolver. Você pode fazer o mesmo em Java, ciente que há um mínimo risco, que pode ser menor se fizer uma boa escolha de nome.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).